# is there a way to render rtf string to html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, rtf

sorry for my poor english in advance.

what i wanna do is, to retrieve a raw text data of rich text that has sjis data in it from the DB, then somehow render the rich text in website i created.

what i mean by raw text data of rich text is String data of something like following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset128 \'82\'6c\'82\'72 \'96\'be\'92\'a9;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;\red0\green77\blue187;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\cf1\b\f0\fs22\lang1041\'82\'a0\'82\'a2\'82\'a4\'82\'a6\'82\'a8\cf0\b0\par

\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\qc\cf2\i\'82\'a9\'82\'ab\'82\'ad\'82\'af\'82\'b1\cf0\i0\par

\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\qr\cf3\ul\'82\'b3\'82\'b5\'82\'b7\'82\'b9\'82\'bb\cf0\par

\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\ulnone\strike\'82\'bd\'82\'bf\'82\'c2\'82\'c4\'82\'c6\par
\strike0\lang17\par
}
```

i tried apache TIKA. but what it can do is decode text data in readable string. that can't reproduce font-color, style, family, alignment.

i tried converting rich text into html using JEditorPane. this can reproduce font color and style, but can't reproduce alignment and resulting in garbled characters. containing text data is SJIS but decoded as UTF8. i can't find the way to force JEditorPane to use specific character code.

i tried a jquery plugin that allows you to create rich text editor on your website. but it can't use the raw text data of rich text as its input data.

is there any way to render rich text in website by using server side java or client side javascript?

Comment: Did you search at all for this?  The 4th Google hit is https://github.com/iarna/rtf-to-html.

Comment: For a server side solution, see link in my profile or [this library](https://www.scroogexhtml.com). Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.